# How do I keep ezSQL connection alive?

Tags: php, mysql, ezsql

I am using ezSQL in a script that is running in a loop for days, possibly weeks. The connection is defined and created outside of the loop. However when a long time passes I get this MySQL error:
    MySQL server has gone away

I guess mysql has disconnected the ezSQL connection?

What I wonder... does ezSQL auto-reconnect, because I can't find any reconnect function? How do you propose I check the connection/health of ezSQL?

Comment: Why don't you put the connection inside the loop and redefine the connection after some arbitrary number of iterations?

Comment: I think ping is the proper way to go

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php

Comment: More accurately for ezSQL

mysqli_ping($db->dbh);